# cellForRowAt not being called but numberOfRowsInSection is

Tags: swift, uitableview, icarousel

So, I have checked that `tableview.reloadData()` is being called on the main thread and that `numberOfRowsInSection` has values. When I look at the view hierarchy the tableView is clearly there and shows the background colour when set. What I have noticed that is odd is that the view hierarchy says its an Empty list(understandable) but it contains two UIImageView's one in the top right and one in the bottom left. Don't understand this at all. My tableView is nested in an iCarousel which I'm sure is where the issue lies. My code is entirely programmatic, so here is what i think may be of value:

iCarouselDatasource:(carousels dont have cells but views instead)

```
class BillCarouselDataSource: NSObject, iCarouselDataSource {

    var bills = [Bill]()

    func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
        return bills.count
    }

    func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let bill = bills[index]
        let billCarouselView = BillCarouselView(bill: bill)
        billCarouselView.frame = carousel.frame
        billCarouselView.setupView()

        return billCarouselView
    }
}
```

iCarousel view(cell)

```
class BillCarouselView: UIView {

    private var bill: Bill!

    private let nameLabel = CarouselLabel()
    private let locationLabel = CarouselLabel()
    private let dateLabel = CarouselLabel()
    private let splitButton = CarouselButton()
    private let tableView = UITableView()

    required init(bill: Bill) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        self.bill = bill
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func setupView() {
        setupHierarchy()
        setupViews()
        setupLayout()
    }

    private func setupHierarchy() {
        addSubview(nameLabel)
        addSubview(locationLabel)
        addSubview(dateLabel)
        addSubview(tableView)
        addSubview(splitButton)
    }

    private func setupViews() {
        accessibilityIdentifier = AccesID.carouselView
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        layer.cornerRadius = Layout.carouselViewCornerRadius
        backgroundColor = Color.carouselView

        nameLabel.text = bill.name
        nameLabel.textAlignment = .center
        nameLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = AccesID.carouselNameLabel

        locationLabel.text = bill.location
        locationLabel.textAlignment = .left
        locationLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = AccesID.carouselLocationLabel

        dateLabel.text = bill.creationDate
        dateLabel.font = Font.carouselDateText
        dateLabel.textAlignment = .right
        dateLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = AccesID.carouselDateLabel

        let dataSource = CarouselTableViewDataSource()
        let delegate = CarouselTableViewDelegate()

        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.dataSource = dataSource
        tableView.delegate = delegate
        tableView.register(CarouselTableViewCell.classForCoder(),
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: "carouselTableViewCell")
        dataSource.items = bill.items
        tableView.reloadData()

        let buttonTitle = "Split £\(bill.totalPrice())"
        splitButton.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
    }

    private func setupLayout() {
        nameLabel.pinToSuperview(edges: [.top, .left, .right])

        locationLabel.pinToSuperview(edges: [.left],
                                     constant: Layout.spacer,
                                     priority: .required)
        locationLabel.pinTop(to: nameLabel, anchor: .bottom)
        locationLabel.pinRight(to: dateLabel, anchor: .left)

        dateLabel.pinToSuperview(edges: [.right],
                                 constant: -Layout.spacer,
                                 priority: .required)
        dateLabel.pinTop(to: nameLabel, anchor: .bottom)

        tableView.pinTop(to: dateLabel, anchor: .bottom)
        tableView.pinToSuperview(edges: [.left, .right])
        tableView.pinBottom(to: splitButton, anchor: .top)

        splitButton.pinToSuperview(edges: [.left, .right, .bottom])
    }
}


class CarouselTableViewDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    var items: [Item]? {
        didSet {
            let duplicatedItems = items
            filteredItems = duplicatedItems?.filterDuplicates { ( $0.creationID ) }
        }
    }

    private var filteredItems: [Item]!

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredItems.count
    }

    //Set what each cell in the tableview contains.
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: CarouselTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "carouselTableViewCell") as! CarouselTableViewCell
        let duplicateItems = items?.filter { Int($0.creationID)! == indexPath.row }
        let quantity = "\(duplicateItems!.count) x "
        let name = duplicateItems![0].name
        let price = formatPrice(duplicateItems![0].price)

        cell.quantityLabel.text = quantity
        cell.nameLabel.text = name
        cell.priceLabel.text = price

        return cell
    }

    private func formatPrice(_ stringPrice: String) -> String {
        var formattedPrice = stringPrice
        let price = NSNumber(value: Double(stringPrice)!)
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        if let formattedTipAmount = formatter.string(from: price) {
            formattedPrice = "Tip Amount: \(formattedTipAmount)"
        }
        return formattedPrice
    }
}
```

class CarouselTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
var containerView = UIView()
var quantityLabel = UILabel()
var nameLabel = UILabel()
var priceLabel = UILabel()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: "carouselTableViewCell")

    setupHierarchy()
    setupViews()
    setupLayout()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:)")
}

private func setupHierarchy() {
    containerView.addSubview(quantityLabel)
    containerView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    containerView.addSubview(priceLabel)
    containerView.addSubview(containerView)
    contentView.addSubview(containerView)
}

private func setupViews() {
    quantityLabel.textAlignment = .left
    quantityLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
    quantityLabel.textColor = Color.carouselText

    nameLabel.textAlignment = .left
    nameLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
    nameLabel.textColor = Color.carouselText

    priceLabel.textAlignment = .right
    priceLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
    priceLabel.textColor = Color.carouselText

}

private func setupLayout() {
    containerView.pinToSuperview(edges: [.left, .right])
    containerView.pinToSuperviewTop(withConstant: -2, priority: .required, relatedBy: .equal)
    containerView.pinToSuperviewBottom(withConstant: -2, priority: .required, relatedBy: .equal)

    quantityLabel.pinToSuperview(edges: [.top, .left, .bottom])

    nameLabel.pinToSuperview(edges: [.top, .bottom])
    nameLabel.pinLeft(to: quantityLabel, anchor: .right)
    nameLabel.pinRight(to: priceLabel, anchor: .left)

    priceLabel.pinToSuperview(edges: [.top, .right, .bottom])

    }
}
```

Everything in the iCarousel view(cell) shows apart from the contents of the cell.

Any help or insight would be great

Comment: I know you said that `numberOfRowsInSection` provides values but can you print `filteredItems.count` inside that method for a typical run to show what those values are?

Comment: Yes, just tried and it prints 0 for the first view(cell) and 7 for the second. The first is supposed to 0 and the second is supposed to be 7.

Comment: @Wrumble Did you found solution for this problem? I have same problem.

Comment: Yes i did, i had an error in my custom cell caused by this line `containerView.addSubview(containerView)` after this i had to move `tableView.register` before setting the datasource(`tableView.dataSource = dataSource`) but after initialising the datasource(`dataSource = CarouselTableViewDataSource()`) I will add a full answer later after work